# Header not found, depending on platform (iPhone Xcode)

Tags: iphone, xcode, header, sdk

I added 'Header Search Paths' to my Xcode project.
when I compiled for iPhone simulator it ran well.
but when I set the target to iPhone Xcode says that the header cannot be found.
I didn't do anything except changing Device/Simulator

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The targets have Header Search Path declarations too. Check, if something get overwritten. Or check, if both targets have the same paths in it.

Comment: Ugh, still it didn't work. I just created new project and imported old code files and it worked. Maybe it was because of messed up configuration I guess

Comment: yeah, I had to do that when moving some projects fro 3.x to 4. i just couldnt figure out, what was wrong.